# Зачем нужны абстрактные классы коллекций помимо интерфейсов?

Tags: java, коллекции

Почему в Java, кроме интерфейсов коллекций, есть соответствующие им абстрактные классы. Например, есть интерфейс `Collection`. и абстрактный класс `AbstractCollection`, `List` и `AbstractList`. Почему недостаточно только интерфейса?

Comment: Загляните в их код, полюбопытствуйте. Там реализованы базовые фичи коллекций и списков, не зависящие от конкретной реализации, позволяющие сократить объем кода в конкретных классах.

Comment: @Nofate, тогда не совсем понятно, зачем интерфесы.

Comment: Затем что вас никто не обязывает наследоваться от этих абстрактных классов при реализации своих коллекций. Интерфейсы как и положено интерфейсам описывают контракт. Абстрактные классы предоставляют скелет для реализации.

Comment: @Nofate, Не совсем понятно, для чего тогда, например, класс ArrayList наследует AbstractList и имплементирует интерфейс List?

Comment: @jisecayeyo Вы имеете ввиду, что если `ArrayList` унаследован от `AbstractList`'a, то какой смысл дописывать `implements List`? По сути, на функционал это не влияет (Проверял по аналогии со своей программой), кроме случая, когда абстрактный класс реализует более одного интерфейса. А так, судя по всему это сделано в угоду читаемости кода. Однако, я могу чего-то не учесть.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Абстрактные классы - это helper-классы, предоставляющие базовую умолчательную "скелетную" реализацию функциональности соответствующих интерфейсов. Например, класс `AbstractCollection` предоставляет пользователю "скелетную" реализацию интерфейса `Collection`. Для того, чтобы реализовать свою коллекцию, вам нужно просто унаследоваться от `AbstractCollection` и предоставить свои собственные реализации тех методов, которые специфичны для вашей коллекции. А те, которые неспецифичны - просто унаследуются в готовом виде из `AbstractCollection`. Таким образом вам не нужно будет писать ворох "скучных" методов с тривиальной или рутинной реализацией.

В то же время вы не обязаны пользоваться `AbstractCollection`. Вы имеете полное право, если вам так захочется, реализовать интерфейс `Collection`своими силами, с нуля, не пользуясь услугами `AbstractCollection`.

Точно также проведено разделение между `List` и `AbstractList`.

Comment: Это соответствует какому-нибудь паттерну проектирования?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, почему, например, класс ArrayList наследует AbstractList и имплементирует интерфейс List?

Comment: @jisecayeyo: А мне не понятно, что тут может быть непонятного. Назначение `ArrayList` именно и заключается в том, чтобы реализовывать массив, доступный через интерфейс `List`. В полном соответствии с моим ответом, авторы `ArrayList`, чтобы сократить объем рутинной работы, воспользовались "скелетной" реализацией, предоствляемой `AbstractList`.

Answer (score 0):

Проще скажем так:

**интерфейс** : это характеристика класса, при чём характеристик может быть много
**абстрактный класс-предок** : это ядро класса, зачастую стратегия поведения

То есть вещи весьма разные - не удивительно, что для одного и того же класса присутствуют обе концепции.

Comment: Тогда не совсем понятно, почему, например, класс ArrayList наследует AbstractList и имплементирует интерфейс List?

Comment: @jisecayeyo ну в человеческих терминах List - это его характеристика, сразу ясно, что это список. AbstractList - это стратегия поведения списка. А ArrayList - класс использующий эту стратегию, и расширяющий поведение - не просто список, а список-массив. Надобность интерфейсов заключается (ИМХО) - в том, что ты сразу видишь, какими характеристиками обладает класс - можно найти классы с подобными характеристиками, посмотреть где юзаются. Т.е. это нужно не только чтобы полиморфизм работал - читаемость и человекоподобность кода в больших проектах первостепенна.

Answer (score 0):

`Interface` - показывает, что объет класса обладает каким то поведением, но без указание того, как он это делает

`Abstract class` - идея та же самая, но в нем, как правило, уже присутствует частичная реализация. Это позволяет избавиться от дублирования кода в классах потомках. С `abstract class` широко используется паттерн проектирования [`template method`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). Приведу пример из того же `java.util.AbstractList`. Там есть метод `addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c)` имеющий конкретную реализацию, в нем вызывается `add(int index, E element)`, который в свою очередь уже является абстрактным.